# How to generate an empty styling template with class names from html

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I find myself typing the class names in JSX then typing the same class names as selectors in CSS/SCSS quite frequently.
Is there any simple way to not do these twice because it seems like something almost every react developer has to do but I cannot find any tools regarding this by searching.
To clarify is there any tool to generate this sass *template* or a plain CSS one:

```
.chatContainer {
  .chat {
    .chatHeader {
    }
    .chatBody {
    }
    .chatFooter {
      .messageInput {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

from this:

```
<div className="chatContainer">
  <div className="chat">
    <div className="chatHeader"></div>
    <div className="chatBody"></div>
    <div className="chatFooter">
      <div className="messageInput">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

supporting BEM style class names would be a nice addition too

Answer (score 1):

I use [Hygen](http://www.hygen.io/) for code scaffolding, especially when working with react to create my components, modules, services, etc. I hope this helps you.